# SEVERE: Servlet.init() call for Servlet [appServlet] caused an exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets

While implementing CRUD with a spring, this error occurred and has not been able to proceed with CRUD for several hours...

"Line 7 of the xml document of the servlet context resource [/web-inf/spring/appservlet/slaplet-slap.xml] is invalid."

Even if line 7 is erased, line 6 is an error and line 5 is an error if erased once again, so I don't think this is an empty tag problem.

Just in case, I'll put the controller and dao.

I'm worried that it'll be uncomfortable to watch. sorry..
help me!!

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/article")
public class ArticleController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArticleController.class);
    private final ArticleService articleService;

@Inject
public ArticleController(ArticleService articleService) {
    this.articleService = articleService;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/write", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String writeGET() {
    logger.info("write GET...");
    return "/article/write";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/write", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String writePOST(ArticleVO articleVO, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
    logger.info("writePOST...");
    logger.info(articleVO.toString());
    articleService.create(articleVO);
    ;
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "regSuccess");
    return "redirect:/article/list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String list(Model model) throws Exception {
    logger.info("list ...");
    model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.listAll());
    return "/article/list";
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/read", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String read(@RequestParam("article_no") int article_no, Model model) throws Exception {
    logger.info("read ...");
    model.addAttribute("article", articleService.read(article_no));
    return "/article/read";
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/modify", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String modifyGET(@RequestParam("article_no") int article_no, Model model) throws Exception {
    logger.info("modifyGet ...");
    model.addAttribute("article", articleService.read(article_no));
    return "/article/modify";
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/modify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String modifyPOST(ArticleVO articleVO, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
    logger.info("modifyPOST ...");
    articleService.update(articleVO);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "modSuccess");
    return "redirect:/article/list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String remove(@RequestParam("article_no") int article_no, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("remove ...");
    articleService.delete(article_no);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "delSuccess");
    return "redirect:/article/list";
}
}
```

DAO

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/article")
    public class ArticleController {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArticleController.class);
        private final ArticleService articleService;
    
    @Inject
    public ArticleController(ArticleService articleService) {
        this.articleService = articleService;
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/write", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    
    public String writeGET() {
        logger.info("write GET...");
        return "/article/write";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/write", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    
    public String writePOST(ArticleVO articleVO, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
        logger.info("writePOST...");
        logger.info(articleVO.toString());
        articleService.create(articleVO);
        ;
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "regSuccess");
        return "redirect:/article/list";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    
    public String list(Model model) throws Exception {
        logger.info("list ...");
        model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.listAll());
        return "/article/list";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/read", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String read(@RequestParam("article_no") int article_no, Model model) throws Exception {
        logger.info("read ...");
        model.addAttribute("article", articleService.read(article_no));
        return "/article/read";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/modify", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String modifyGET(@RequestParam("article_no") int article_no, Model model) throws Exception {
        logger.info("modifyGet ...");
        model.addAttribute("article", articleService.read(article_no));
        return "/article/modify";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/modify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String modifyPOST(ArticleVO articleVO, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
        logger.info("modifyPOST ...");
        articleService.update(articleVO);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "modSuccess");
        return "redirect:/article/list";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    
    public String remove(@RequestParam("article_no") int article_no, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
            throws Exception {
        logger.info("remove ...");
        articleService.delete(article_no);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "delSuccess");
        return "redirect:/article/list";
    }
    }
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
        
     <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure --> <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven /> <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up 
        static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources mapping="/plugins/**"
        location="/resources/plugins/" />
    <resources mapping="/dist/**" location="/resources/dist/" /> <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.cameldev.httpsession" />
</beans:beans>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"> 

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/injo?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="howang12" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory"
        class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation"
            value="classpath:/mybatis-config.xml" />
        <property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath:mappers/**/*Mapper.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSession"
        class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate"
        destroy-method="clearCache">
        <constructor-arg name="sqlSessionFactory"
            ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cameldev.httpsession" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: And line 7 is what?

Comment: This is the part of servlet-context.xml.          
'xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).